# Depth First Search Logic Recursive Function

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, depth-first-search

I have some code where I simulate a player trying to escape from a dungeon in a dungeon-crawler game. I want to use depth-first search to test whether the player can succeed.

Something goes wrong in my method, inside the Dungeon class, that should test whether *every* path out of the dungeon will be successful:
Here is my print statements:

```
self = <main_test.GraphTest testMethod=test_can_all_paths_make_it>

    def test_can_all_paths_make_it(self):
        dungeon = self.create_dungeon()
>       self.assertEqual(dungeon.can_all_paths_make_it(Player(11)), False)
E       AssertionError: True != False

coderbyte-tests/main_test.py:140: AssertionError
----------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
Checking node: <graph.Monster object at 0x7f82158aa190>, Current Health: 11
Checking neighbor: <graph.Monster object at 0x7f82158aa130>
Encountered Monster: <graph.Monster object at 0x7f82158aa130>
Checking node: <graph.Monster object at 0x7f82158aa130>, Current Health: 7
Checking neighbor: <graph.Monster object at 0x7f82158aa040>
Encountered Monster: <graph.Monster object at 0x7f82158aa040>
Checking node: <graph.Monster object at 0x7f82158aa040>, Current Health: 2
Checking neighbor: <graph.Treasure object at 0x7f8215914850>
Processing neighbor: <graph.Treasure object at 0x7f8215914850>
Checking node: <graph.Treasure object at 0x7f8215914850>, Current Health: 2
Found Treasure!
```

```
# Will any path make it to the end? Can they choose randomly and always make it?
    def can_all_paths_make_it(self, player: Player) -> bool:
      def dfs(node, current_health):
        if isinstance(node, Treasure):
          return True

        if current_health <= 0:
          return False
        
        if node is not node.next:
          return False
        
        for neighbor in node.next:
                if isinstance(neighbor, Monster):
                    # Simulate a battle with the monster
                    new_health = current_health - neighbor.damage
                    if not dfs(neighbor, new_health):
                        return False
                elif not dfs(neighbor, current_health):
                    return False

        return True

      return dfs(self.monster, player.health)
```

It seems that the logic is slightly off, because some test cases fail. (The test cases will not show exactly where I am off other than expecting True when it output False).

I know that in order to test whether all paths can make it I need to consider the dead ends, the loss of health and if they are at Treasure.

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Here are the test cases

```
import unittest
```

from graph import Monster, Treasure, Player, Dungeon

class GraphTest(unittest.TestCase):

```
# a(3) -> b(4) -> c(5) -> treasure
def create_dungeon(self) -> Dungeon:
    a = Monster("a", 3)
    b = Monster("b", 4)
    c = Monster("c", 5)
    treasure = Treasure()
    a.append_monster(b)
    b.append_monster(c)
    c.append_treasure(treasure)

    return Dungeon(a)

# a(3) -> b(4)  c(5) -> treasure
def create_dungeon2(self) -> Dungeon:
    a = Monster("a", 3)
    b = Monster("b", 4)
    c = Monster("c", 5)
    treasure = Treasure()
    a.append_monster(b)
    c.append_treasure(treasure)

    return Dungeon(a)

# a(1) -> b(4)
#   |      |
#   v      v
# c(2) -> d(1) -> treasure
def create_dungeon3(self):
    a = Monster("a", 1)
    b = Monster("b", 4)
    c = Monster("c", 2)
    d = Monster("d", 1)
    treasure = Treasure()
    a.append_monster(b)
    a.append_monster(c)
    b.append_monster(d)
    c.append_monster(d)
    d.append_treasure(treasure)

    return Dungeon(a)

# a(1) -> b(4) -> e(1)
#   |      |
#   v      v
# c(2) -> d(1) -> treasure

'''
Probability review: Just because there are 2 different possiblilites does not 
mean that they are equal probability. For example, on any given day, there could be 
rain or no rain. That doesn't imply that rain has a 50% chance.

In this case, there are 3 different paths:
a->c->d->treasure, a->b->d->treasure, and a->b->e. 

Here, a->c->d->tresure has a 50% chance of happening, a->b->e is 25%, and a->b->d->treasure is 25%. 
An easy way to think about it that the probability of A reaching C is 50% and C reaching D is 100%
and D reaching Treasure is 100%. Overall, it would be 50% chance to do A->C->D->Treasure.
'''
def create_dungeon4(self):
    a = Monster("a", 1)
    b = Monster("b", 4)
    c = Monster("c", 2)
    d = Monster("d", 1)
    e = Monster("e", 1)
    treasure = Treasure()
    a.append_monster(b)
    a.append_monster(c)
    b.append_monster(d)
    c.append_monster(d)
    b.append_monster(e)
    d.append_treasure(treasure)

    return Dungeon(a)

# a(1) -> b(5) -> e(1) 
#   |      |       |       
#   v      v       v        
# c(2) -> d(7) -> f(2) -> treasure
# optimal -> a -> b -> e -> f
def create_dungeon5(self):
    a = Monster("a", 1)
    b = Monster("b", 5)
    c = Monster("c", 2)
    d = Monster("d", 7)
    e = Monster("e", 1)
    f = Monster("f", 2)
    treasure = Treasure()
    a.append_monster(b)
    a.append_monster(c)
    b.append_monster(e)
    b.append_monster(d)
    c.append_monster(d)
    d.append_monster(f)
    e.append_monster(f)
    f.append_treasure(treasure)

    return Dungeon(a)

# a(1) -> b(5) -> e(1) ------
#   |      |       |        |
#   v      v       v        v
# c(2) -> d(7) -> f(2) -> treasure
# optimal -> a -> b -> e -> f
def create_dungeon6(self):
    a = Monster("a", 1)
    b = Monster("b", 5)
    c = Monster("c", 2)
    d = Monster("d", 7)
    e = Monster("e", 1)
    f = Monster("f", 2)
    treasure = Treasure()
    a.append_monster(b)
    a.append_monster(c)
    b.append_monster(e)
    b.append_monster(d)
    c.append_monster(d)
    d.append_monster(f)
    e.append_monster(f)
    e.append_treasure(treasure)
    f.append_treasure(treasure)

    return Dungeon(a)

def test_can_at_least_one_path_make_it(self):
    dungeon = self.create_dungeon()
    self.assertEqual(dungeon.can_at_least_one_path_make_it(), True)
    
    dungeon = self.create_dungeon2()
    self.assertEqual(dungeon.can_at_least_one_path_make_it(), False)


def test_can_all_paths_make_it(self):
    dungeon = self.create_dungeon()
    self.assertEqual(dungeon.can_all_paths_make_it(Player(11)), False)

    dungeon = self.create_dungeon()
    self.assertEqual(dungeon.can_all_paths_make_it(Player(12)), True)

    dungeon = self.create_dungeon2()
    self.assertEqual(dungeon.can_all_paths_make_it(Player(7)), False)
    
    dungeon = self.create_dungeon3()
    self.assertEqual(dungeon.can_all_paths_make_it(Player(5)), False)

    dungeon = self.create_dungeon3()
    self.assertEqual(dungeon.can_all_paths_make_it(Player(6)), True)

    dungeon = self.create_dungeon4()
    self.assertEqual(dungeon.can_all_paths_make_it(Player(100)), False)

def test_probability_player_will_make_it(self):
    dungeon = self.create_dungeon()
    self.assertEqual(dungeon.probability_player_will_make_it(Player(12)), 1.0)

    dungeon = self.create_dungeon()
    self.assertEqual(dungeon.probability_player_will_make_it(Player(11)), 0.0)
    
    dungeon = self.create_dungeon2()
    self.assertEqual(dungeon.probability_player_will_make_it(Player(100)), 0.0)

    dungeon = self.create_dungeon3()
    self.assertEqual(dungeon.probability_player_will_make_it(Player(1)), 0.0)

    dungeon = self.create_dungeon3()
    self.assertEqual(dungeon.probability_player_will_make_it(Player(5)), 0.5)

    dungeon = self.create_dungeon3()
    self.assertEqual(dungeon.probability_player_will_make_it(Player(100)), 1.0)

    dungeon = self.create_dungeon4()
    self.assertEqual(dungeon.probability_player_will_make_it(Player(1)), 0.0)

    dungeon = self.create_dungeon4()
    self.assertEqual(dungeon.probability_player_will_make_it(Player(5)), 0.5)

    dungeon = self.create_dungeon4()
    self.assertEqual(dungeon.probability_player_will_make_it(Player(100)), 0.75)

def test_can_make_it(self):
    dungeon = self.create_dungeon5()
    self.assertEqual(dungeon.can_make_it(Player(9)), True)

    dungeon = self.create_dungeon5()
    self.assertEqual(dungeon.can_make_it(Player(8)), False)

    dungeon = self.create_dungeon6()
    self.assertEqual(dungeon.can_make_it(Player(7)), True)

    dungeon = self.create_dungeon6()
    self.assertEqual(dungeon.can_make_it(Player(6)), False)
```

For myself, I created this print statement
def can_all_paths_make_it(self, player: Player) -> bool:
def dfs(node, current_health):
print(f"Checking node: {node}, Current Health: {current_health}")

```
    if isinstance(node, Treasure):
        print("Found Treasure!")
        return True

    if current_health <= 0:
        print("Player has lost all health!")
        return False

    if not isinstance(node.next, list):
        print("Invalid path: node.next is not a list")
        return False  # If node.next is not a list, it's not a valid path

    for neighbor in node.next:
        print(f"Checking neighbor: {neighbor}")

        if isinstance(neighbor, Monster):
            print(f"Encountered Monster: {neighbor}")
            # Simulate a battle with the monster
            new_health = current_health - neighbor.damage
            if not dfs(neighbor, new_health):
                return False
        elif not dfs(neighbor, current_health):
            return False

    return True

return dfs(self.monster, player.health)
```

Comment: We can't really help with failing test cases if we don't know what the failing test cases are, or what is supposed to happen in them. We don't "find the bug" for you here generally; you [are expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) before posting to a) identify a **concrete, reproducible** problem and b) **isolate where** the problem occurs by [carefully checking what happens when the code runs and looking for something that is different from what you expect](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: That said: I can't understand the intended purpose of `if node is not node.next: return False`. Think carefully about the logic there. In order for the rest of the code to be tried, we need the assumption that this condition **isn't** met, right? Therefore, what do we know about `node` when the loop starts? Does that make sense? For that matter: it seems as though `node.next` should hold a *list of* nodes, since there is a `for` loop over it. Right? Could a list of nodes **ever** be the same object as a node?

Comment: Please provide the code to initialise a dungeon state for which your code returns the wrong result.

Comment: It looks off that you pass in `self.monster` in `dfs` for `node` as the first argument. But as the others have said, you need to provide a concrete example and question, otherwise, this will deteriorate into a guessing game.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel No, each node is a separate element with its value. I guess I should be assigning a current node to equal node.next?

Comment: A "dumb" but unreasonably effective approach to see what your code does is to run it on a single failing test case, and have `print` statements at every line in the function that goes wrong, printing the state known to the code at that line. Run it once, now you have a log to go through that _should_ let you see where what happens stops matching what you thought should have happened based on what you thought you implemented.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans
Here is what it displays
Checking node: Current Health: 11
Checking neighbor: 
Encountered Monster: 
Checking node: , Current Health: 7
Checking neighbor:
Encountered Monster: 
Checking node:  Current Health: 2
Checking neighbor: 
Checking node: Current Health: 2
Found Treasure!
So it shows that all paths make it

Comment: Don't put details in comments. [Put them in your post](/help/how-to-ask) so everyone can see them. And then you can comment going "I've updated my post with the result of that" or the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues:

- `if current_health <= 0` will evaluate to True when health is zero, but that is still an acceptable health.
- The health is only reduced by the damage of neighboring monsters, but not by the damage of the very first monster. You should move that damage-logic out of the loop and apply it to the current node.
- `if node is not node.next:` does not make sense. This condition is always going to be True. You'll want to test for dead ends with `if not node.next:`

Here is the corrected code:

```
    def can_all_paths_make_it(self, player: Player) -> bool:
        def dfs(node, current_health):
            if current_health < 0:  # the player died
                return False
            
            if isinstance(node, Treasure):  # bingo!
                return True

            if isinstance(node, Monster):  # have to fight
                current_health -= node.damage
 
            if not node.next:   # dead end
                return False

            return all(dfs(neighbor, current_health) 
                       for neighbor in node.next)

        return dfs(self.monster, player.health)
```

Comment: thank you I was missing the instance of node, moster decrementing the health within that if statement, MUCH APPRECIATED!!